# Problem while installing Android Studio

Tags: permissions, android-studio

I had once installed android studio once and while it was updating the files got corrupt and I was getting a message to install it from scratch. So first I went to `/usr/local/` and deleted the directory `android-studio` (*Probably my biggest mistake*) then I extracted  **android-studio-2020.3.1.25-linux.tar.gz** in `/usr/local/` from after that for some reason I am not able to access it without going as root. What shouuld I do?

Following is the output I am getting after using `cd /usr/local/`

> `bash: cd: /usr/local/: Permission denied`

Comment: Check the permissions: `ls -ld /usr/local`.

Comment: Android Studio by Google for Ubuntu https://launchpad.net/~maarten-fonville/+archive/ubuntu/android-studio

Comment: @mikewhatever trying it out I got 
>`drwx------ 11 root root 4096 Jan  1  2010 /usr/local
`

Comment: Those permissions allow access to root only. The default is `drwxr-xr-x`, so you might want to change it: `sudo chmod 755 /usr/local`.

Comment: @mikewhatever thanks I got the access